# winsock "invalid argument" error on listen

Tags: c++, winsock

I was trying to make a simple client - server communication application, but I've come across a problem - I get error 10022 ( invalid argument ) on listen.

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;
sockaddr_in addr;
SOCKET sock, client;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons( 25565 );
addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );

iResult = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &wsaData );

if( iResult )
{
    std::cout << ( WSAGetLastError( ) );
    _getch( );
}

sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

if( sock == INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    std::cout << ( WSAGetLastError( ) );
    _getch( );
}

iResult = listen( sock, SOMAXCONN );

if( iResult )
{
    std::cout << ( WSAGetLastError( ) );
    _getch( );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you `listen`, you need to `bind` the socket to the port that will be listened on.

It looks like you have already built the address structure containing the information necessary to `bind`, so call `bind(sock, &addr, sizeof(addr))` and perform appropriate error checking  before the call to `listen`.

[Documentation for `bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [`listen()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen):

> WSAEINVAL
>
> The socket has **not been bound with [`bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind)**.

You need to `bind()` the socket before you can `listen()` on it.